As a custom Android launcher, how to determine (via code) if an app's notification setting is turned off?
I am writing a custom launcher via Android APIs. While displaying the notifications coming from the apps, I would like to filter out the notifications if it is coming from the apps for which the user has disabled the notifications, since there are still some apps out there which still keep sending the notifications even though the notifications are disabled!
Does anyone know how to detect if the app has the notification disabled. To begin with, all I have is the packageName of the app for which the notifications are coming through!
Thank you!
Not sure if this is the right direction or not, but I found the following:
NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.From((Context)mainActivity.ApplicationContext);
nm.AreNotificationsEnabled();

But the problem is that it is only applicable to my own app, because the context here is my own apps context.
How do I change the context to the other app which I am interested in?
